# Module class suffix in Yootheme Joomla template

Tags: css, joomla

In Joomla 2.5, I add the module class suffix "barra" to a certain module.
In the frontend I can see the class "barra" has been added to the module.

In modules.css, I included:

```
.barra {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But the style of the module doesn't change, I can see from Firebug that it isn't being read at all. I included the same code in layouts.css but nothing... Where can I add the css for a module class suffix?

Comment: Check the head of the page source for what template css files are being included. Then use one of those. I'm not familiar with Yootheme to be more specific

Comment: have you tried using `background-color: red !important;` ? It might also be due to the fact that a child element background is overlapping the `.barra` background

Comment: Yes, tried that too. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working... without any changes.

It turned out to be a cache problem.

Thanks for your help anyway.